# Implementing a chat bot

Tags: javascript, android, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I'm having a problem while wrapping up my android chatbot with JavaScript. Actually I'm using IBM Watson Conversation service for natural language processing and an Android app will be the client side, but I don't know how to manage request and response between the server and Android app.

Comment: sdk-nodejs could be a choice for your server side application.

Comment: please provide some more background.

Answer (score 3):

See the Watson Conversation starter on Bluemix which will provide you a working Android app using the Watson Conversation service:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/mobile/create-project/

[image: Example Screenshot]